# "Remember Me" with enabled totp authentication in WSO2 Identity Server doesn't work

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, totp, wso2-identity-server

I have a running productive WSO2 Identity Server (Version wso2is-5.6.0) and a new clean testing instance (Version 5.9.0) and using identity providers with 2Factor authentication. (basic and totp).

When both of them are active, the "rember me" function doesn't work anymore.
When i disable the totp authentication, the "Remember Me" function works and the Session keeps active when the Browser is closed.

Does anybody know, if that's a configuration issue, a error or just doesn't work like that?

Configuration in the deployment.toml:

```
[session_data.persistence]
enable_persistence = true
persist_temporary_data = true
persistence_pool_size = "0"

[session_data.cleanup]
enable_expired_data_cleanup = true
expire_session_data_after = "14d"
clean_expired_session_data_every = "1d"
clean_expired_session_data_in_chunks_of = "8192"
clean_logged_out_sessions_at_immediate_cycle = "true"

enable_pre_session_data_cleanup = true
pre_session_data_cleanup_thread_pool_size= "20"
expire_pre_session_data_after= "40m"
```

Comment: When the user choose "remember me" option, commonAuthId cookie expiry is set to some value. Can you please check the expiry time of the commonAuthId cookie?

Comment: When i login with only one authentication step (basic auth) the lifetime is set to 20160 minutes.

When i add a second authentication step (totp) the liftetime is set to "end of browser session".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the bug in the product. Thank you for reporting this.  I have created a git [issue](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/7441) to track and fix this. We will fix this in the next weekly release.